# Using LINQ to return just two specific DataTables in a DataSet with several DataTables

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, dataset

How can I use LINQ to return just two specific DataTables in a DataSet with several DataTables? For example, in the code snippet below, is it possible to add LINQ to `myDS.Tables` in the `foreach` statement?

I want to remove the `if` statement if possible.

```
 DataTable myTable1 = new DataTable("MyTable1");
 DataTable myTable2 = new DataTable("MyTable2");
 DataTable myTable3 = new DataTable("MyTable3");
 DataSet myDS = new DataSet();
 myDS.Tables.Add(myTable1);
 myDS.Tables.Add(myTable2);
 myDS.Tables.Add(myTable3);

 foreach (DataTable table in myDS.Tables)
 {
    if (table.TableName != "MyTable1" && table.TableName != "MyTable2")
    {
        continue;
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Table Name = " + table.TableName);
 }
```

Comment: You can't use LINQ, because `DataTableCollection` does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`, which is needed by LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use linq by using the `Cast` function of `IEnumerable` and then use the filter function `Where` in order to get your result.
Your if statement should become a predicate for the Where function.

```
  var tables = myDS.Tables.Cast<DataTable>()
                          .Where(t=> t.TableName == "MyTable1" || t.TableName == "MyTable2");
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of foreach block, u can use:

```
        myDS.Tables
            .OfType<DataTable>()
            .Where(table => new string[] { "MyTable1" , "MyTable2" }.Contains(table.TableName))
            .ToList().ForEach(table =>
            {

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Table Name = " + table.TableName);
            });
```